# Jquery Dialog and stacked buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just wondering if anyone knows how to get the buttons to stack in a Jquery modal window?  It looks like this:

```
$confirm.dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 140,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        show: "blind",
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Button 1",
                click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); },
                class:'ok_button'
            },
            {
                text: "Button 2",
                click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); },
                class:'ok_button'
            },
            {
                text: "Button 3",
                click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); },
                class:'ok_button'
            }
        ],
        create: function(event, ui){
           console.log($(event.target).prev().remove());
           console.log(ui);
        }
    });
```

This puts the buttons side by side, any clues?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: add css class `.ok_button {clear:both;}`

Comment: Sorry, that didn't do the trick

Comment: What's your question? How do you like to style the buttons?

Comment: try this post it shows you how to style the buttons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138291/jquery-dialog-save-cancel-button-styling

Comment: I am asking how to stack the buttons on top of one another instead of side by side.  Side by side is the Jquery default.

Comment: Yeah, you need to style them. See gilly's post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: block`:

```
.ok_button { display: block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NMyHG/